# How to configure specific paths for an endpoint different from others?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a catch-all endpoint (in my case it's the Blazor Server endpoint) and want it generally to require authorization:

```cs
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host").RequireAuthorization();
```

That works, but there is one special page inside the Blazor Server app that should be public (and that won't link to the rest). I now tried to map part of the paths as a different endpoint:

```cs
app.Map("/public", app2 => app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host"));

app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host").RequireAuthorization();
```

That gives me an exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Using ExpandEndpoint requires that the replaced endpoint have a unique priority. The following endpoints were found with the same priority: ...
```

I'm asking this question also to more generally understand this endpoint routing, specifically how I can fork a given endpoint. I'm not just looking for a workaround, such as allowing the Blazor Server app always unauthenticated and redirect from there if no user is present.

Comment: Hi @John, did you mean you want to use the `MapFallbackToPage` in the map route and want to know why it gives exception?

Comment: @Rena Yes, and how to avoid the exception of course.